# Data redundant when getting from SQL Server view?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have created a view from multiple tables join. In the view, data is not redundant but when I am getting from lambda expression it showing same data two times.

Actually I have made application for mobile recharges where two types of users

1. Distributer
2. Retailer

If retailer recharge any number commission add both account for retailer and distributer.

Data in view :

```
SN  RCV_ID  RCV_AMT  CURRENT_BAL  COMM_AMT  RCV_UID   ID
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   10955   100.00   17.09        0.70      10203     10955
2   10955   100.00   10.85        0.90      10199     10955
```

View :

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  dbo.tbl_recharge.ID) AS SN, 
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.RCV_ID, dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.RCV_TYPE, 
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.RCV_AMT, dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.CURRENT_BALANCE, 
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.PRE_BALANCE, dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.COMM_AMT, 
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.ADMIN_PROFIT AS RCV_ADMIN_PROFIT, 
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.CLIENT_PROFIT AS RCV_CLIENT_PROFIT, 
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.RCV_DATE, 
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.INSRT_TMSP AS RCV_INSRT_TMSP, 
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.UID AS RCV_UID, 
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.INSRT_USER AS RCV_INSRT_USER, 
    dbo.tbl_recharge.ID, dbo.tbl_recharge.REF_ID, 
    dbo.tbl_recharge.NUMBER, dbo.tbl_recharge.STATUS, 
    dbo.tbl_recharge.AMT, dbo.tbl_recharge.OPERATOR, 
    dbo.tbl_recharge.TYPE, dbo.tbl_recharge.INSRT_TMSP, 
    dbo.tbl_recharge.INSRT_USR, dbo.tbl_recharge.UID, 
    dbo.tbl_operator.OPERATOR AS OPERATOR_NAME, 
    dbo.tbl_commission.YOUR_PROFIT, dbo.tbl_commission.ClIENT_PROFIT, 
    dbo.tbl_commission.SERVICE, dbo.tbl_commission.USER_TYPE, 
    dbo.tbl_commission.OPERATOR_ID, dbo.tbl_user.PRNT_ID, 
    dbo.tbl_user.USR_TYPE_ID
FROM
    dbo.tbl_paymentHistory 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.tbl_recharge ON dbo.tbl_paymentHistory.RCV_ID = dbo.tbl_recharge.ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tbl_operator ON dbo.tbl_operator.PROVIDER_ID = dbo.tbl_recharge.OPERATOR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.tbl_commission ON dbo.tbl_commission.OPERATOR_ID = dbo.tbl_operator.ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tbl_user ON dbo.tbl_user.ID = dbo.tbl_recharge.UID 
                 AND dbo.tbl_user.USR_TYPE_ID = dbo.tbl_commission.USER_TYPE
```

But when I get it from a lambda expression, its gets the first row multiple times :

```
ViewBag.rechargeHistory = db2.v_recharge_payment_History.OrderByDescending(x => x.SN)
.Where(x => x.INSRT_TMSP >= startDate && x.INSRT_TMSP <= endDate).ToList();
```

I have spent lots of time but nothing getting......

I have no idea what I do? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle problem with *views* when used from Entity Framework.

If you have a table, do use it with EF, you need to have a **primary key** to uniquely identify each row. Typically, that's a single column, e.g. an `ID` or something like that.

With a view, you don't have the concept of a "primary key" - the view just contains some columns from some tables.

So when EF maps a view, it cannot find a primary key - and therefore, it will use *all non-nullable columns* from the view as "substitute" primary key.

I don't know what these are in your case - you should be able to tell from the `.edmx` model or your model classes.

When EF reads data, it checks to see if it already knows the primary key - so it gets your first line of data, stores it and then goes on to read the second line of data from your query. If the **substitute primary key** that EF applied to the view data is the same (e.g. all **non-nullable columns** are the same), then it interprets this second line of data **as the same as before* and doesn't look at the rest of the columns.

So the problem really is that you can't have explicit primary keys on a view.

The solution is to include **all the underlying table's primary key columns** in your view - in that case, every line of data in your view should always have uniquely identifying values, and thus should be interpreted as separate rows of data.

Comment: i have adding a ROW_NUMBER() as a SNo so can i make it primary key ?